# Path / URL error in application created for Django/Python course I'm taking

Tags: python, django, url, path

[This is the error I receive from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLbys.jpg)

This is the code of the app urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    # sets home page to all current blogs that are published
    path('about/',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    path('post/<int:pk>',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    # will match primary key to whatever we click on
    path('post/new/',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/remove/',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
    path('drafts/',views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='post_draft_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/approve',views.comment_approve,name='comment_approve'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/remove',views.comment_remove,name='comment_remove'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/publish',views.post_publish,name='post_publish'),
]
```

This is the code of the site urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views # just importing some prefab views for authorization

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls')),
    # path('accounts/login',views.login,name='login'),
    path('accounts/login',views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout',views.LoginView.as_view(),name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
    # so when you logout, the next page you go to is the home page
]
```

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have any URL with 'accounts/profile'. Check if you forgot to include the view in your urls file.

Comment: Thanks. That would normally be logical but I don't have a profile page. See my own answer below. Thanks again!

Comment: I gave an upvote but apparently it won't show as you or me have less than 15. What's a tick? Sorry, I'm new to SO and still learning the etiquette.